# Finding the inflexion points of a cubic in $ \mathbb{P}^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}.$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> For what values of $ m $ is the cubic $$ F = x_{0}^{3} + x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{3} + mx_{0}x_{1}x_{2} = 0 $$ in $ \mathbb{P}^{2}_{\mathbb{C}} $ nonsingular? Find its inflexion points.

I know that $$ \text{Sing}(F) = \Big\lbrace F = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{0}} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{1}} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{2}} = 0 \Big\rbrace $$

Using this information, I have that $$ \text{Sing}(F) = \lbrace (x_{0}:x_{1}:x_{2}) \in \mathbb{P}^{2}_{\mathbb{C}} \;|\; x_{0} = x_{1} = x_{2} \rbrace.  $$ That is, $ \text{Sing}(F) = (1:1:1). $ Furthermore, at the singular point of $ F, m = -3. $

I am unsure about how to get the inflexion points. Do I need to compute the determinant of the Hessian matrix where $ m = -3$?

EDIT: Unless I've made an error, the determinant of the Hessian matrix yields $$ 216x_{0}x_{1}x_{2} - 6m^{2}x_{0}^{3} - 6m^{2}x^{3}_{2} + 2m^{3}x_{0}x_{1}x_{2} -6m^{2}x^{3}_{1} = 0 $$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: I think you need to compute the determinant of the Hessian when $m\ne -3$.

Comment: Why when $ m \neq 3$?  Sorry if it's a silly question. @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Because that is when the curve is **non-singular**.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Okay. I've edited my question.

Comment: So now you have two cubic equations. You now have to find the points satisfying both. Anyway, is the coefficient on $x_0^3$ really just $-6m$?

Comment: In maxima `f:x^3+y^3+z^3+m*x*y*z;` `algsys([f,determinant(hessian (f, [x, y, z]))],[x,y,z]);` gives nine flexes, three of which are real: $(0:-1:1), (-1:0:1), (-1:1:0).$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It's -6m^{2}. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve simultaneously the original equation times the Hessian.

Adding $6m^2$ times the original equation to the Hessian gives
$$(216+8m^3)x_0x_1x_2=0.$$
Unless $m^3=-27$ then $x_0x_1x_2=0$ so one of the variables vanishes.
If $x_0=0$ then $x_1^3+x_2^2=0$ so you get three inflection points
$(0:1:-\zeta)$ where $\zeta^3=1$. Overall then, you do get nine inflection points.